# Input to Visual Studio Console Window not showing

Tags: c++, debugging, module, console, stack

I've recently started to learn how to code, and started with C++. The IDE I'm using is Visual Studio Community 2019 on Windows 10 64-bit. I wrote a small code which I wanted to debug using breakpoints. When Visual Studio enters debug mode it gives the following message on the bottom-left corner: "loading symbols for kernel32.dll"  (the message isn't restricted to kernel32.dll, but also ntdll.dll, KernelBase.dll, msvcp.dll, vcruntime140d.dll, ucrtbased.dll). I opened the module tab and automatically loaded all of them (I don't really know what these are, some clarity in this regard would also be appreciated), however, the main issue persists: when I enter a keyboard entry to the console it doesn't show the character entered. After pressing step-into it shows the value that has now been stored inside the declared variable and the entered value on the console, which may or may not have been entered correctly as the character input is invisible in the console window while typing.

Does this have something to do with Stack, Heap management, RAM etc.? Please explain what this issue means and what I can do to solve it as there is no point in debugging if i cannot see what is being printed or entered on the console.

The code is shown below, if it is required (The program takes an input from the user and compares it to a randomly generated number as shown):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int Guess, RandomNumber,End=1;
    srand(time(NULL));
    RandomNumber = rand() % 100 + 1;
    std::cout << "Enter a Number. (HINT: The number lies between 0 and 100!)";
    while (End != 0) //this is where I added a breakpoint.
    {
        do
        {
            std::cin >> Guess;

            if (Guess > RandomNumber)
            {
                std::cout << "You Guess is incorrect. The special number is smaller than your guess! ";
            }
            if (Guess < RandomNumber)
            {
                std::cout << "You Guess is incorrect. The special number is larger than your guess! ";
            }
        } while (Guess != RandomNumber);
        std::cout << "You are CORRECT! The number was: " << Guess<<std::endl<<"Press 1 to play again. To exit press 0"<<std::endl;
        std::cin >> End;
    }
}
```

Comment: What were the line numbers you had set a breakpoint to?

Comment: Nothing requires that the user's input be echoed to the console, but in the vast majority of cases it is. Why it is not in your case I cannot say. If this does turn out to be a misuse of the stack or heap, it's nothing you did.

Comment: @RohanBari look for the `//this is where I added a breakpoint` comment.

Comment: @RohanBari I added one on Line 10 (At the line that says: while(End != 0) ). I have added a comment next to the line too. Any feedback as to why I might be getting this error?

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks for the insight, is there anything I can do with my settings or .cpp file properties to solve this issue?

Comment: I've nothing for you, I'm afraid. I rarely use Visual Studio, and when I do, my organization standardized on 2015 and the console just "worked".

Comment: Side note: When you run your program it has to pull in a number of extra libraries that provide the C++ Standard library, the C Standard Library, and a butt-load of libraries that allow the program to communicate with the Windows OS. The debugger was telling you  it had loaded these libraries because sometimes it's important information to help you track down a missing library or an incorrect library being loaded. Normally you won't need to load these symbols because--even for the experts, gurus and grandmasters--the bug you're hunting is almost certainly at your end.

Comment: @user4581301 so kernel32 etc are actually libraries that are essential for program execution? Also, can background tasks have caused this problem? I have Norton as an antivirus which takes up a significant amount of memory space? Could this be a reason for a “delayed response” in the Visual Studio Console?

Comment: Essential for program execution on Windows. Any heavy-weight OS will have similar requirements. Lighter OSes may statically link the libraries, and "bare metal" applications running directly atop hardware will do whatever the heck they need to do in order to provide support for the Standard Library. Also running Norton. Never had a problem with a non-echoing console.

Comment: @user4581301 Alright, guess there isn’t much that can be done. Thanks!

Comment: I was able to solve the issue by updating Visual Studio 2019 to its latest version: V16.6.0. After this, I disabled the online symbol file (.pdb) location (Microsoft servers) by heading to Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Symbols, and un-checking the option that says: "Microsoft Symbols Server" under "Symbol File (.pbd) locations: " . I then entered debug mode by adding a breakpoint and hitting F5, after which I clicked "Load All Symbols" under the same setting. This seemed to stop the "loading symbols" notification and make the console input visible while typing.